# Creating a new object overwrites existing session (modbus)

Tags: c#, object, modbus

I created a C# DLL using modbus-protocoll to read an analog-value from a module.

In a second c#-project i use the dll and create an object with "new ET18Z_A". Everything works fine as long as i only use one module. When i create a second object (ET18Z_B) then the first is not working any more.

It seems as if the second "new" overwrite the first session.

Here the code that i use to read one value. If the second "new" is skipped and it is running good and function ReadInputRegister reads the correct value. If i make the three lines active and the second "new" is also active then the function ReadInputRegister does not read the correct value. There is also no error but the result is wrong.

```
ET7018Z.ET7018Z ET18Z_A = new ET7018Z.ET7018Z();
string IP_ET7018Z = "192.168.100.110";
Res = ET18Z_A.Initialize(IP_ET7018Z, out Message);

//The next three lines open connection to a second module with different IP
//ET7018Z.ET7018Z ET18Z_B = new ET7018Z.ET7018Z();
//IP_ET7018Z = "192.168.100.210";
//Res = ET18Z_B.Initialize(IP_ET7018Z, out Message);

int AI_7018Z = 0
Res = ET18Z_A.ReadInputRegister(AI_7018Z, out Value, out Message);
```

The Initialize function looks like this:

```
public class ET7018Z
{
    static ModbusIpMaster master;

    public int Initialize(string IP, out string Message)
    {
        Message = "No Error";

        try
        {
            string ipAddress = IP;
            int tcpPort = 502;
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(); 
            tcpClient.BeginConnect(ipAddress, tcpPort, null, null);
            master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(tcpClient);
            Thread.Sleep(100); 

            string message = "";
            int Res = 0;
            Res = SetEngineeringFormat(CState.ON, out message);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to remove the "static" in this line:

static ModbusIpMaster master;